# How can I install tor in the UAE?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, tor

I'm using Linux Mint 10 Julia and currently in the UAE.
I'm having trouble accessing a lot of websites so I want to install tor.
However the the [domain](http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org) is block and so the [repo address](http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org%20maverick%20main) of **tor** itself is blocked.

How can I install it otherwise or are there other links I can try?

---

the problem is not connecting to sites like https://www.torproject.org/ but connecting to the deb repos like http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en) I downloaded the [Tor Browser Bundle for GNU/Linux on i686](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) and it worked.

Comment: Since this fixed your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 2):

If [this](https://tor.beme-it.de/download/download-unix.html.en) doesn't work try these.  I personally would go with the browser bundle. Note: the instructions on these pages are just copies of the ones found on the main site, however many them have separate repo addresses.

```
#
https://www.torservers.net/mirrors/torproject.org/
#
https://www.oignon.net/
#
https://www.torproject.us/
#
https://tor.beme-it.de/
#
https://torproj.xpdm.us/
#
https://tor.blingblingsquad.net/
#
https://tor.tomyn.com/
#
https://tor-www.5coluna.com/
#
http://jan25.virtadpt.net/
```

If all else fails send an empty email (from gmail only)  with the subject HELP to gettor AT torproject.org

Comment: all your links point me to the download install instructions which all requires http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org and that is not usable here :(

Comment: Don't use apt-get. Download the browser bundle for deb such as https://www.torservers.net/mirrors/torproject.org/dist/torbrowser/linux/tor-browser-gnu-linux-x86_64-1.1.8-dev-en-US.tar.gz

Comment: Yes I see the edit to your question and this what concerns me is that you seem to have difficulty understanding tor. This is why I suggested the bundle. If you have trouble with the repo just remember that the DNS is in a round robin configuration so that you can use a part of it without necessarily needing the whole. The examples typically used are deb-master.torproject.org, mirror.netcologne.de or tor.mirror.youam.de

Answer (score 0):

Easy, you can update it:

- install **Vidalia** from software manager
- then install **proxychains**
- kill Tor (`sudo killall tor`)
- start Vidalia and wait until it connects
- add Tor repo to sources list
- in terminal type `proxychains sudo apt-get update`
- Tor will be updated
- use 127.0.0.1 port 9050 in proxy sockets (Firefox)